# yii2 authclient popup is not closed after successfull login

Tags: facebook, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In my website, I install the yii2-authclient, but I have a few issues (I am using facebook,LinkedIn):

when I click on the facebook button it opens a window,
problem is that the login is made inside the popup windows that opens. The main window doesn't be refreshed.
There is any solution for this problems?

I think the popup window should appear and close immediately after the facebook login, and then the main window auto-refresh.
| Yii version | 2.0

Comment: Anyone able to solved this problem?

Comment: Yup!!! I have found the solution it myself. If anyone having this problem then contact me on here!!

Comment: I am encounter the same problem do you remember the solution? Unfortunatly you did not post it here...

Comment: @VanrajKalsariya did you find the issue? Can you please let us know